# Webpack keeps getting disconnected. Chrome Issue?

Tags: google-chrome, webpack

I been having this issue for awhile that I posted on [github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1419) and some of the posts say that it is a google chrome issue.

I followed the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate/47646463#47646463) post but I don't know where to go. I am running google chrome on windows 7.

Comment: You might try cleaning your node_modules and re-installing them again. I had a similar problem with Webpack 2 in MacOS and that solved the issue.

Comment: I tried reproducing the code in your repo. But could not reproduce. Maybe reinstalling the dependencies might help.

Comment: I has the same issue before.
I have deleted node_modules manually and then reinstalled the dependencies with a simple npm i

Hope it helps you too!

Comment: What npm command should I run just npm install?